# Why does my shell function to define aliases not work?

Tags: zsh

I've defined this function in my .zshrc

```
define_shortcut() {
    declare "$1"="$2"
    alias $1="cd $2"
}
```

I then call it

```
define_shortcut $alerts /Users/home/config/alerts/
```

the alias part works, i.e. `alerts` is defined as an alias for `cd alerts` but the declare statement does not work. `echo alerts` shows that no `alerts` variable is defined.

Why doesn't my define_shortcut function work ?

Comment: (1) Tag bash **or** zsh, not both at the same time. (2) There are security problems with this definition. You want to escape your values to be eval-safe before putting them in aliases. I know how to fix that for bash, but not zsh (they're different shells, and not fully compatible; again, **don't tag for both**)

Comment: Also, `echo alerts` is not `echo "$alerts"` or `declare -p alerts`. It's normal and expected for `echo alerts` to just emit `alerts`, whether or not there's a variable named `alerts` defined.

Comment: (in bash 5.0 or later, `alias "$1=cd ${2@Q}"` would fix the security problem caused by maliciously-named directories being able to run arbitrary commands; in older versions of bash one could achieve the same result with `printf %q` to generate a safely-escaped version of the command).

Comment: When you use `declare` inside the function, the variable is unset when the function returns.

Comment: Ah, right; one needs `-g` (in bash, dunno about zsh) for `declare` to create a global.

Comment: Just use `eval "$1='$2'"` There's no need for `declare`

Comment: @Barmar, ...though that's not safe for values of `$2` with literal single quotes (which are legal in paths on common filesystems). In bash 5.0+ one could use `eval "$1=${2@Q}"`, but _shrug_ re: what the zsh equivalent would be.

Comment: True, but it's the basic idea. I don't know what zsh's mechanism for automatic escaping is.

Comment: `echo alerts` should just print _alerts_; for parameter expansion, you need a `$`, i.e. `echo $alerts`.

Comment: `zsh` has an option to allow `$alerts` alone to act like `cd $alerts`; there's no need to define the alias at all.

Comment: (Then you don't even need the function, which ironically involves *more* typing than simply defining `alerts=/Users/home/config/alerts`.)

Comment: @chepner what is this zsh option?

Comment: `setopt AUTO_CD`. (Note that `bash` has a similar option as well, `shopt -s autocd`.)

Comment: You might also be interested in the dynamic named directories feature documented in `man zshexpn`, which lets you customize how tilde expansion works.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the variable is declared in global scope. The following works for me:

```
define_shortcut() {
  typeset -g $1=$2
  alias $1="cd $2"
}
```